# How can I switch memory modules to 1600 Mhz?

Tags: memory, bios

Some months ago I bought 4 Memory modules of 4GB DDR3 1600 KINGSTON HYPERX. The official Kingston manual says:

> *This module has been tested to run at DDR3-1600 at a low latency timing of 9-9-9-27 at 1.65V.The SPD is programmed to JEDEC standard
>   latency DDR3-1333 timing of 9-9-9.

I cannot find which is the real speed of my memory modules. I normally get from several tools that the real speed is 1333 Mhz

```
srs@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmidecode -t memory
# dmidecode 2.9
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x005D, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: 0x005F
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x005C, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005D
    Error Information Handle: 0x0060
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 07288F23
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: 9905403-439.A00LF
```

**How can I switch memory modules to 1600 Mhz?**

Comment: Some BIOSes allow to set timings for memory - if you don't have this setting in BIOS setup then I'm not sure there's a way.

Comment: Have you tried updating your BIOS?

Comment: @Sergey. Kington does not give for a normal user enough information to overclock this particular memory module

Comment: @Mitch. I did update some minutes ago, it seems that I bought a memory module with 1333 Mhz of speed that has been tested with higher speed. This module is sold as a DDR3 1600 Mhz, but in fact it is a DDR3 1333 Mhz.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you, this is not a software issue, rather, it is a hardware issue. You will have to check your motherboard's BIOS settings to see if it allows you to overclock or underclock RAM modules, but still, doing either is kinda risky, and is not guaranteed to offer you better performance.

You also have to note that RAM speed has to do with what your processor supports too. So before anything else, have a look on your processor's manual.

Comment: According to /proc/cpuinfo my processor has 1600 of cpu Mhz. My BIOS allows me to change a dozen of properties within the DRAM Timing Control, but I am not sure which of these I have to change.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://ark.intel.com/products/52210/Intel-Core-i5-2500K-Processor-%286M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz%29 my Intel i5 2500k only supports DDR3-1066/1333, so I do not need to overclock any memory module.